# Words describing types of conversation

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I have three related questions, all concerning words descriptive of conversational habits.

**(1)** How would you choose a word to describe someone who likes to talk about things around them and things happening in their whereabouts?

[The opposite of absent minded]

Actually, absent minded though would not do a very good job at describing someone who likes to talk/think, perhaps not on their own, about abstract things or things they imagine).

**(2)** And how would you choose a word for someone who likes to talk about things happening elsewhere?

**(3)** And how would you choose a word for describing someone who likes to talk about the past?

Comment: What words have you found yourself? Why didn't they work? :)

Comment: What does "the opposite of absent-minded" have to do with anything here?

Comment: Can you provide a context as to where these words would be used (for example, why would you want to differentiate between these three people); because I don't see a specific need to identify these types of individuals, unless it is accompanied by some other trait - for example, as part of an imaginary band of travelers or revelers; in which case you would be _describing their acts_ (thus, an expression) and not looking for a single word.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an adage sort of thing, though not that popular, that goes:

> **Local-minded** people will never understand **global-minded** goals.

It's easy to look it up on Google.

As to your third question, you've not made it clear what you're after exactly. Does the person talk about the past wistfully? Or boastfully? Or in what manner?
Anyway, you can consider these words/expressions:

> - [*reminiscent*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reminiscent):
>     1.1 Absorbed in or suggesting absorption in memories:
>     "*Her expression was wistful and reminiscent*."
> - [*nostalgic*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nostalgic):
>     Feeling, evoking, or characterized by [nostalgia](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nostalgia):
>     "*He remained nostalgic about the good old days.*"
> - [*dwelling on/upon*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dwell#dwell__10) + *the past*:
>     "*I’ve got better things to do than dwell on the past.*"

Comment: Would you call a person at one's wits' end, local minded? Are you assuming a Euclidean or fractal-like topology. Sorry, for the stupidity, but I see Stack Exchange as neither local not global, perhaps distributed would be a better word.

Comment: Anyways, I don't feel any of my questions for this post have been properly answered.

Comment: Your downvote would've been more welcome than blaming my fault on everybody here. I may have misunderstood your question. Please feel free to edit your question to make it clearer and bring it back to the query queue of the first page.

Comment: BTW, what about _parochial_ instead of _local-minded_?